# Using static variables and methods vs. non-static

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am developing an ASP/c# webform where I am using JQuery as well. I came into a scenario where I need to call. C# function from JQuery. In order to that, I found that function in c# has to be a static method (web method).

The problem is that I need to access all variables, arrays, etc which I used to populat some data and these are not stated c variables. Also, from the web method I need to re-use some the functions which are not static. I ended up gradually just changing all methods and variables to static.

I would like to know if the approach I am taking is correct, and whether there is any pitfall of using static variables/methods and what in simple words makes a difference between static/none-static.

Comment: provide some code dude.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? What dotnet framework are you using, MVC, webforms, core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables can be called directly by using class names such as

```
public class IhaveStatic
{
   public static string Hello = "Hello I am A";
}
```

When you use static this means this will be in memory for life time of your process.

now consider another class as

```
public class IhaveNoStatic
{
   public string Hello = "Hello I am B"
}

public class C
{
      Console.WriteLine(IhaveStatic.Hello);    // Correct
      IhaveNoStatic obj = new IhaveNoStatic();
      Console.WriteLine(obj);                  // Correct
      Console.WriteLine(IhaveNoStatic.Hello);  // Compile time error
 }
```

as you can see that you need to create object of that class "**IhaveNoStatic**" to access non-static variable. So, this will be in memory until there is an instance of that class exist.

So, basically it's on your requirement but it is good to use less static variable in your programs.